# Sturm-Liouville theory.

Tags: mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to prove a theorem concerning inhomogeneous Sturm-Liouville system. Let's consider a system
$$
\begin{cases}
(p(x)y(x)')'+(\lambda r(x) - q(x))y(x) = f(x), \\
y(a)=A, y(b) = B.
\end{cases}
$$
From differntial equations we know that if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue for $L \equiv - \frac1r \frac{d}{d x} \left( p(x) \frac {d}{d x} \, \right) + \frac{q(x)}{r(x)}$, then the system has a unique solution. But I want to proof that if $L y_n = \lambda_n y_n$, then the following 2 statements are equivalent:
$$
\exists y \, - \, \text{solution} \Leftrightarrow \int\limits_a^b f(x) y_n(x) d x = A p(a) y_n'(a) - B p(b) y_n'(b).
$$

Comment: Did you try something? Did it lead anywhere? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I don't even have any ideas :(

Comment: For the direct part - multiply both sides of the equation by $y$ and then integrate from $a$ to $b$. A integration by parts should do the trick.

Comment: Surely I tried that. No results. And also I tried $(py')'=(py'y)'-p(y')^2$, and then integrate. Still no results.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you wrote down the question correctly?

Comment: Yes. It is an additional task from a lecture.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume $\lambda_n=\lambda$ is real, that the first integral to the right of the equivalence should be $\int_a^bf(x)y_n(x)r(x)\,dx$ and that $y_n(a)=y_n(b)=0$. Then all you have to do is integration by parts twice, like this:
$$
 \int_a^bfy_nr=\int_a^b(-(py')'+(q-\lambda r)y)y_n=
 (-py'y_n+ypy_n')|_a^b+\int_a^by(-(py_n')'+(q-\lambda r)y_n)
=py'(a)y_n(a)-py'(b)y_n(b).
$$